# How do you deal with decimal precision of increasing float values in GLSL?

Tags: floating-point, glsl, shader, precision, floating-accuracy

I'm writing a shader where I need to calculate y-value based on an increasing x offset.

The problem is that the increasing x value will eventually lose its decimal precision causing the output of the y function to return increasingly fragmented values.

I've tried to illustrate the problem in this [example](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/WttGWB).

You can increase or decrease the `largeTimeOffset` variable to see the effect it has on the detail of the sine wave. Is there a common way to tackle this problem?

Fragment shader for reference:

```c
float calculateY(float x, float y) {
    return  y + sin(x);
}

void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    vec3 bgColor = vec3(0.0);
    vec3 lineColor = vec3(0.0);
    float lineWidth = 0.001;

    vec2 uv = fragCoord/iResolution.xy;

    uv  = -1.0 + 2.0 * uv;
    uv.y += 0.1;

    float largeTimeOffset = 1000000.0;
    float x = (uv.x + (iTime + largeTimeOffset));

    float y = calculateY(x, uv.y);
    lineWidth = abs(1.0 / (300.0 * y));     
    lineColor += vec3(lineWidth, lineWidth, lineWidth);


    fragColor = vec4(bgColor+lineColor,1.0);
}
```

Comment: Why float, not double?

Comment: GLSL doesn't support double

Comment: @stego `double` is supported since OpenGL ES 3.2 (GLSL ES 3.20) or "desktop" OpenGL 4.0 (GLSL 4.00), respectively by the extension [ARB_gpu_shader_fp64](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_gpu_shader_fp64.txt). See [Data Type (GLSL)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL))

Answer (score 2):

First of all note, that the data type `double` is supported since "desktop" OpenGL 4.0 (GLSL 4.00), respectively by the extension [ARB_gpu_shader_fp64](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_gpu_shader_fp64.txt).
See [Data Type (GLSL)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL))

---

Since [`sin`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/sin.xhtml) is a periodic function, the issue can be solved by calculation the offset within a period by [`mod`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mod.xhtml). The period is 2*PI respectively `2.0*acos(-1.0)`:
(`mod` is available in all GLSL respectively GLSL ES versions)

```c
float x = uv.x + mod(iTime + largeTimeOffset, 2.0*acos(-1.0));
```

Of course this is a special solution for the trigonometric functions `sin` and `cos`

Comment: Minor: Curious, why use 3.141593 versus a more precise value of pi?  3.141593 does not yield the best pi approximation available in `float`.  A good machine pi is the result of `acos(-1)`.

Comment: I think I could use your suggestion to work around the issue in my case.

However it seems to me that the lost decimal precision will still affect the final result.

The curve looks smooth with your suggestion _but_ the decimal precision is still lost when increasing the `largeTimeOffset`, it's just not just not affecting the smoothness of the curve anymore.

Comment: @stepo It is still unclear what you try to achieve. For a perfect result calculate *`mod(time, 2*PI)`* on the CPU (with *double* precision) and set the value to a uniform. In your example `float x = uv.x + iTime  + mod(largeTimeOffset, 2.0*acos(-1.0));` will also give a good result, but I don't think that will solve the issue in a "real" situation.

Answer (score 0):

@Rabbid76 mentioned that the fp64 extension works on OpenGL ES 3.2, but in the [specs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_gpu_shader_fp64.txt) it says that the minimum supported version is OpenGL 3.2 which is not equivalent to OpenGL *ES* 3.2.
To actually use double-precision floating point numbers in OpenGL ES, you have to emulate it. For the trigonometric functions, you can use the taylor series expansions of those functions.

Comment: *Any* version of OpenGL might support the extension (or not) -- you need to query it to see if it does.  The extension was written against OpenGL 3.2 as that was the prevalent version at the time of publication.  OpenGL 4.0 (and later) support `double` natively without the extension (though they probably also advertise that they support the extension).  I don't think any version of OpenGL ES supports it natively, but any implementation of any version might support the extension.